# Pull OS information from Sentinel Syslog

Tags: operating-system, pull

Can someone help me to create K-Query to pull OS information Windows, Mac etc from Sentinel Syslog?
Pull OS type report from Syslog in specific time frame.

I'm new to K-Query and still trying to figure out how I can tackle small requests.